# Create network option missing on macOS Sonoma despite legacy networks being enabled

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I am trying to create a local WiFi network using my macOS Sonoma computer.

I followed a guide online and I enabled legacy network options but I cannot create a new network on the WiFi button at the top.

I attached images, any help is appreciated.

Legacy networks enabled:
[image: legacy networks enabled]

Create network option missing:
[image: create network option missing]

Comment: It appears you are connected to a wireless network. How are you expecting to both be connected to a wireless network and create one using the same wireless adapter?

Comment: I was connected to wifi to post the question but even when I disconnected from the wifi the option still doesn’t show

Answer (score 4):

You can use the terminal using this commands:

```
sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice AdHoc lo0
```

Enter

```
sudo networksetup -setmanual AdHoc 192.168.1.88 255.255.255.255
```

Enter

Then you go Settings > General > Internet sharing

You need to select the 'i' and choose AdHoc in "Share my internet from", and below you choose 'Wi-Fi'. This will open the WiFi Options where you can name the network and set a password (which imo is safer than the traditional way of setting up an AdHoc network).

Now when you want to start the network you only need to turn on the Internet Sharing Access and the network you named will be available for other devices.

Hope this helped!

Comment: this worked thanks. just one more question. when creating the network like this what's the command to delete it?

Comment: See `networksetup -help` for help about the available commands. The inverse of `networksetup -createnetworkservice <newnetworkservice> <hardwareport>` seems to be `networksetup -removenetworkservice <networkservice>`. So, `sudo networksetup -removenetworkservice AdHoc` should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo networksetup -removenetworkservice AdHoc` doesn't work, giving an error `You cannot remove AdHoc because there aren't any other network services on Loopback.`. I had to use `sudo networksetup -deletepppoeservice "AdHoc"`. As a side note, this answer didn't work for me, my network exists but no devices can actually connect to it.

Comment: This keeps disconnecting after a minutes of being idle. Does this happen to you?

Comment: These had a lot of side effects on my end. Be careful with these commands. I wonder how to revert it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me anymore. The iPhone can connect to the shared WiFi, but it can't ping the laptop's IP or use its `.local` domains.

Comment: Worked for me. You might want to make sure any any cellular data services are disabled, and or check your DNS servers (if using 1.1.1.1/8.8.8.8 etc .local/mDNS won't work)

Answer (score 0):

Took me awhile to find this too but you need to switch on internet sharing in Settings, then go to 'Wi-Fi options', enter admin password and then setup a wifi network.

https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchlp1540/14.0/mac/14.0